# I can't use HttpServlet T-T

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I can use Servlet, it is nothing wrong: 
[image]

this is my Servlet code:
[image]

Configuration of web.xml:
[image]

But when I use HttpServlet, the mistake happened:
[image]

this is My HttpServlet code:
[image]

and this is Configuration of it:
[image]

I already inspect the things all i imagine. 
I have found a lot of places that have no results，
I am a senior high school student in grade two, 
If the text is in a mess, I'm sorry, I don't know why the pictures in here will be links. Whether you can help me or not, I still want to thank you for see it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please avoid to put image links in your questions, and put your code snippets instead, otherwise you might not have much help here...

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Be careful about just dropping all your code here. Rather focus on getting some minimal, yet complete enough thing together! And you absolutely do put up **code** as screen shots. Anything that is **text** should be **formatted text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
   super.doGet(req, resp);
```

This is delegating to the default implementation of `doGet` provided by the `HttpServlet` class.  The problem is that that version of `doGet` is version that is used when you don't implement your own `doGet`, and its behavior is to tell the remote client that `GET` is not supported by the servlet.

Solution:  remove that call.